# My mac is changing the creation date of files

Tags: macos

Every time I edit files, my computer saves them and changes the creation date of the files, but I want to preserve the creation date of each one. How to do it?

Comment: We need more info. What OS, what type of files, what app? How are you saving the files specifically, just Save or Save as…? Where are you saving to? Where are you checking the created dates? By default simply changing content & saving as the same document should preserve the original creation date - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t37U.png

Comment: I am using macOS 10.13.6, I noticed it in word, excel and pzfx, when I do only save, never save as? Where are you checking the created dates? I do control+mouse click on the file/ get info.  By default simply changing content & saving as the same document should preserve the original creation date, but is not preserving, it is assuming the modification date as a creation date. the two dates are the same.

Comment: I can't repro, sorry - https://i.stack.imgur.com/78jxP.png - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m73i.png on Mojave, Word 16.54

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem, but I may be able to explain it. To avoid problems if an error occurs partway through saving a document, many programs use some sort of "safe" or "atomic" safe process. Basically, they save the new data in a new file under a temporary name, then delete the original file & rename the temp file into its place. The net result is that, while it looks like the file was only modified, it was actually replaced by a similar-looking but actually completely new file.

This means that the new file actually was created when the changes were saved. But normally, the save process will copy the creation date from the old file, and set the new one's creation data the same. It may be that this step -- basically faking the creation date of the new file -- isn't working for some reason on your system.

Here's an example of how it's supposed to work. I created a new file in Word, then checked its stats with the `stat` command:

```
$ stat -f 'inode: %i, create: %SB, mod: %Sm' test.docx 
inode: 12909090453, create: Nov 26 00:12:10 2022, mod: Nov 26 00:12:11 2022
```

Then I changed the file in Word, saved again, and repeated the `stat` command:

```
$ stat -f 'inode: %i, create: %SB, mod: %Sm' test.docx 
inode: 12909090661, create: Nov 26 00:12:10 2022, mod: Nov 26 00:13:31 2022
```

Note that the creation date is the same (i.e. this is not showing the problem you're seeing), the modification date has changed. So did the inode number -- basically an identifier of which file it is on the disk -- has changed. The new inode is how you can tell that the file was replaced, rather than simply having its contents changed.

As for why this isn't working for you, I have no idea. Are these files being stored on some other filesystem (like a network server, external drive in some non-Apple format, or something like that)?